# Can´t convert chr to numeric in R-studio

Tags: r, dataframe

I get NA´s when i try to convert into numeric values (see below)

[image]

Im supposed to make these annual dataframes into monthly ones. to do this i need to make the numbers numeric. I get NA´s when i try to do this. does anyone know?

Comment: You are trying to convert an unlisted data frame consisting of both date strings and numeric strings to numbers. Try `as.numeric(TBS[,2])` instead. And please, don't post pictures of data or code. Post the code and data as text, otherwise people have to transcribe stuff across to test it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Allan :) When i do this, I get the error message: `list`object cannot be coerced to type `double`

Answer (score 0):

When you `unlist()` the data frame, it turns it into a vector.  Here's a couple of lines of the data that I can see from your post (with shorter variable names).

```
TBS <- tibble::tibble(
  desc = c("1934-01", "1934-02"), 
  rate = c("0.72", "0.6")
)
unlist(TBS)
#     desc1     desc2     rate1     rate2 
# "1934-01" "1934-02"    "0.72"     "0.6"
```

When you do `as.numeric()` on that vector, it turns the dates into missing.  I think that's what the output above in your RStudio window shows us.

```
as.numeric(unlist(TBS))
# [1]   NA   NA 0.72 0.60
```

You're probably better off just fixing the variables in place in the data frame, like this:

```
library(zoo)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
TBS <- TBS %>% 
  mutate(desc = as.yearmon(desc),
         year = year(desc), 
         rate = as.numeric(rate))

TBS
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  desc        rate  year
#  <yearmon>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Jan 1934   0.72  1934
# 2 Feb 1934   0.6   1934
```

Then you could do whatever you need (e.g., average) over the years.  If it was just a straight average, you could do.

```
TBS %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(mean_rate = mean(rate))
```

Comment: Hello @DaveArmstrong. thanks for your reply ^^I tried your code. Then i got this error > TBS <- TBS %>% 
+   mutate(desc = as.yearmon(desc),
+          year = year(desc), 
+          rate = as.numeric(rate))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `desc`.
x cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'
ℹ Input `desc` is `as.yearmon(desc)`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.                                             I am trying to make it numeric so that i can divide col 2 by 12, so it transforms from annual to monthly

Comment: Hi @ThommasEspeland - did you run the code and get the error on my toy dataset or on your real data?  If the latter, it would require that the two variables in your dataset be `desc` and `rate`.  You could make this happen with `names(TBS) <- c("desc", "rate")`.  The error you get is saying that it can't find `desc` in the dataset and so it's finding instead a function called `desc` which is in the `dplyr` package.

Comment: You made my day 10x better Dave! thanks. I got an exam assignment on R, even though we have never done anything in R before, so this is a nightmare haha